# Push Topics permissions lost in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets

I have created a managed package that includes a Permission set that provides Read, Create, Edit and Delete permissions on Push Topics. However, when I install that package in a test org (Enterprise), the same Permission set is there but shows No Access for Push Topics.

I've opened up the package contents in the test org, and I'm looking at it side-by-side with the contents of the package in the packaging org. Access is there in the packaging org package, but not in the test org installed package. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions for Standard objects and fields do not migrate with manage package. The idea behind this is your manage package can spoil the configurations of client org. Client can themselves create permission set on their org and provide permission there.

Similarly System permissions also does not migrate in the package because of the same reason.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Frodo. I'm thinking I'll use the post-install apex to either add that permission to my permission set, or creates a new permission set if necessary. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/permission-set-possibly-preventing-installation-of-managed-package